# Mobile left-push menu

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have this menu http://meetsingledating.com/test/. When i click on the button "M", the menu push from the left.

I don't want the button "M" to be grey tint when the menu is open, I would like it like this:

http://meetsingledating.com/test/2.jpg

And when the menu is open and i click on the button "M", i would like to menu to close the same way when it's grey tint.

I already tried a higher z-index and position on the button but it doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

Remove this:

```
#wrapper {
    z-index:10; // <--- remove this
}
```

Add this:

```
.buttons button {
    z-index: 16; // <---
    position: relative; // <---
}
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkkNijboer/e6ngmgfg/

---

**UPDATE:**

I changed the function for the button a bit. Now it checks whether the menu is open or not:

```
/* push menu left */
togglePushLeft.addEventListener( "click", function(){
    if(classie.has(body, "pml-open")) {
        classie.remove( body, activeNav );
        activeNav = "";
        document.body.removeChild(mask);
    } else {
        classie.add( body, "pml-open" );
        document.body.appendChild(mask);
        activeNav = "pml-open";
    }
} );
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkkNijboer/e6ngmgfg/1/

Comment: It works, thank you. The problem is when the menu is open and i click on the button "M" it remains open, it should close.

Comment: Thanks it works. But is there any way to leave the z-index:10; on the wrapper and make the button appears?  Thank you.

Comment: @AdrienParad Short answer: no. The wrapper contains the button. By setting z-index to 10 means everything in this wrapper will not have a higher z-index than 10 (the button as well). The mask has an z-index of 15 so by setting the z-index of the button to 16 and removing the wrapper z-index you get the result you want.  Btw. I saw you have two masks at the moment. I don't that black screen is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try SIDR http://www.berriart.com/sidr/
It's a jQuery plugin capable of implementing this functionality. It is also customizable.
Basic usage

`

```
<a id="existing-content-menu" href="#existing-content-menu">Existing content</a>
<a id="remote-content-menu" href="#remote-content-menu">Load remotelly</a>
<a id="callback-menu" href="#callback-menu">Callback loaded</a>

<header id="demoheader">
<h1>Demos &amp; Usage</h1>
</header>

<div id="demo-content">
<p>Here are described differents ways of usage for this plugin, you can read and adapt them to your website's requeriments. Below are described all options with details.</p>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#existing-content-menu').sidr({
name: 'sidr-existing-content',
source: '#demoheader, #demo-content'
});
$('#remote-content-menu').sidr({
name: 'sidr-remote-content',
source: 'http://www.example.com/remote-menu.html'
});
$('#callback-menu').sidr({
name: 'sidr-callback',
source: function(name) {
return '<h1>' + name + ' menu</h1><p>Yes! You can use a callback too ;)</p>';
}
});
});
</script>
```

`